# SSAS permission issue--Sorry I figure it out while writing this, so just share it out

Tags: permissions, ssas

I installed SSAS in a SQL Server 2016 SP2 CU15 Developer Edition server. At the last step, it prompted out this message

[error message after installation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vX6kB.jpg)

And the SSAS stopped running, when I tried to start it in SSCM manually, failed, the error message is like this:

[image: error message when starting SSAS service]

I patched it with the latest CU17 and tried to start the service again, still failed, the same error.

I changed the service account to "build-in, local service" in SSCM, it worked, the SSAS can be brought online.

Then I changed the service account back to domain\account, it failed again, the error message is like this.[error message of applying service account](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GSQaq.jpg)

I added the service account to the Windows Administrators group, tried to apply it in the SSCM, it worked.

I guess it must be some Windows-level permission issues.

Then I found this:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2012/ms143504(v=sql.110)?redirectedfrom=MSDN#Windows%20Configure%20Windows%20Service%20Accounts%20and%20Permissions

SSAS should be granted the following permission on local security policies

1. Log on as a service (SeServiceLogonRight)
2. For tabular only--(mine is tabular, not sure for cube):

   - Increase a process working set (SeIncreaseWorkingSetPrivilege)
   - Adjust memory quotas for a process (SeIncreaseQuotaSizePrivilege)
   - Lock pages in memory (SeLockMemoryPrivilege) – this is needed only when paging is turned off entirely.
3. For failover cluster installations only:

   - Increase scheduling priority (SeIncreaseBasePriorityPrivilege)

It works.